# How do I remove any lenses or other software that I might consider spying on me? Can it be turned off?

Tags: 12.04, privacy

I heard a bit about Ubuntu installing ad-ware and spyware to track online searches of users. 
Examples are - unity-lenses-shopping, the built in Amazon ad app, and the ad server etc.

I understand that this may be to generate revenue for canonical. But, I want to remove it all. Is there a guide for removing all such spyware ?

Also, is there a paid version of Ubuntu which does not have all this nasty stuff?

Answer (score 5):

From `Privacy` setting you can turn off `include online result`.

If you want to remove lens

type:`sudo apt-get purge unity-lens-shopping`

Answer (score 3):

You can just turn off online results form the dash by going to **System Settings** > **Security and Privacy** and on the search tab turn off the option:

[image]

Also in your web browser you can turn off any integration with web apps by going to **Preferences** and on the general tab turn off the *Prompt integration options from any site*

[image]

As a final resort you can always remove the complete shopping lens integrated to the dash by running:

```
sudo apt-get remove unity-lens-shopping
```

Ubuntu also overs a lot of other desktop environments that you can use that do not share the same type of technology implementations that the dash contains: [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/), [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/), [Ubuntu GNOME](http://ubuntugnome.org/), etc. Just choose one that fits you needs.

Answer (score 2):

you can try the following from [fixubuntu](https://fixubuntu.com/):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Figure out the version of Ubuntu that you're running
V=`/usr/bin/lsb_release -rs`

# The privacy problems started with 12.10, so earlier versions should do nothing
if [ $V \< 12.10 ]; then
  echo "Good news! Your version of Ubuntu doesn't invade your privacy."
else
  # Turn off "Remote Search", so search terms in Dash don't get sent to the internet
  gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Lenses remote-content-search none

  # If you're using earlier than 13.10, uninstall unity-lens-shopping
  if [ $V \< 13.10 ]; then
    sudo apt-get remove -y unity-lens-shopping

  # If you're using a later version, disable remote scopes
  else
    gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Lenses disabled-scopes \
      "['more_suggestions-amazon.scope', 'more_suggestions-u1ms.scope',
      'more_suggestions-populartracks.scope', 'music-musicstore.scope',
      'more_suggestions-ebay.scope', 'more_suggestions-ubuntushop.scope',
      'more_suggestions-skimlinks.scope']"
  fi;

  # Block connections to Ubuntu's ad server, just in case
  if ! grep -q productsearch.ubuntu.com /etc/hosts; then
    echo -e "\n127.0.0.1 productsearch.ubuntu.com" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts >/dev/null
  fi

  echo "All done. Enjoy your privacy."
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

> Also, is there a paid version of Ubuntu which does not have all this nasty stuff?

There is a lightweight and less commercial version of Ubuntu called `Xubuntu` (or `Lubuntu`). I never heard of any privacy issues with the latter two, and many people prefer them for their functionality. If you want to avoid the nasty stuff, give them a try.

Comment: Thanks. UEFI support is the main concern for me. Privacy comes after that.

Comment: If Ubuntu supports UEFI, then so will Xubuntu or Lubuntu. No possible issues here. Xubuntu is mostly Ubuntu running with Xfce.